# Firefox won't play .WAV files using the HTML5 <audio> tag?

Tags: html, firefox, audio, html5-audio

I'm building a page that will allow a user to upload an MP3 file.  That MP3 file is converted in the back end to a .WAV file using LAME.

The lame execution script is here:

```
LAME --resample 44.1 -decode myDirectoryPath/Master.mp3 myDirectoryPath/Master.wav
```

However, when I use the HTML5 audio tag to create a player for that audio file in Firefox, it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="myDirectoryPath/Master.mp3">
        <source src="myDirectoryPath/Master.wav">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything I've read says that Firefox supports .wav files... and I can't find a simple .mp3 to .ogg command line tool to use that will convert the master.mp3 to .ogg format.  Can someone offer some suggestions on what to try next?

I've posted code that works in Safari and Chrome here:
http://www.wgbh.org/byers/Audio/index.html

For whatever reason, FF doesn't like it.

**UPDATE**
(With accompanying facepalm)  The issue lies with my LAME decode.  The correct syntax is --decode with two dashes instead of one.  The system was actually encoding it from mp3 to mp3, naming it wav and Safari / Chrome on the Mac was assuming the file type.

Comment: try adding a `type="audio/wav"` to the `source` tag

Comment: No luck.  The type="audio/wav" did nothing.

Comment: It seems to work if you don't provide the sources. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/kq2EJ/

Comment: Weird... for me it doesn't work putting the src attribute in the audio tag.  But either way, I need multiple sources since I'm going to be delivering mp3 files by default, and wavs for browsers that don't support mp3.

Comment: FF support ogg file use ogg extension file and it work fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's the bit depth on your WAV files?  Firefox supports 8-bit and 16-bit PCM, but not other bit depths (12, 20, 24, 32).

Comment: In addition to this, it won't play back wav files using alaw or ulaw encoding.

Comment: Up votes because I didn't think to check if my wav files were encoding PCM or ulaw.

Comment: As for today, Firefox will play all bitrates up to 32 if it has PCM encoding

Answer (score 3):

Firefox expects one of the following [codecs to be returned as the MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements):

- audio/wave (preferred)
- audio/wav
- audio/x-wav
- audio/x-pn-wav

Make sure your server returns one of those MIME types for wav files.

Comment: Done.  I've tried using type="audio/wave" and "audio/wav" with no results.

Comment: u tried using those types, but did you make sure your server can handle them?

Comment: Webkit browsers will assume a file type based on file extension when a MIME type isn't returned by the server so that could be why your code works in Safari but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the bit depth issue, Firefox HTML5 audio apparently does not play back 6-channel audio, either.  For my app, I needed to re-rip to change both bit depth and number of channels (e.g. sox *inFile* **-b 16 -c 2** *outFile* *otherParams*).

Answer (score -1):

This is bug in Firefox - you need to list the MP3 format source to the end, and it will work.

Comment: This has an accepted answer from 3 years ago, why would you post?