# How to play a wav audio file with jQuery? Why can't the wav file be decoded?

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to get a wav file to play when the Submit button is pressed.

For some reason I keep seeing this error:
Media resource file:///Users/Bryan/webapp/buzzer.wav could not be decoded.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>   
    <head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>  
</head>   

<body>   

<audio id="buzzer" src="buzzer.wav" type="audio/wav">Your browser does not support the &#60;audio&#62; element.</audio>  
<form id='sample' action="#" data-ajax="false">  
    <fieldset>  
     <input value="Start" type="submit">  
     </fieldset>  
</form>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

var buzzer = $('buzzer')[0];  

$(document).on('submit', '#sample', function()  {  
    alert("submitted");  
    buzzer.play();  
    return false;  
});  

</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem lies with your wav file, and possibly the specific browser that you are in.

See this related post: [Firefox won't play .WAV files using the HTML5 <audio> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404005/firefox-wont-play-wav-files-using-the-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Note that at time of writing FireFox won't play 24bit .wav files.  Convert them to 16 bit and they'll be happy.