# Javascript audio not working in Firefox (x-unknown/unknown)

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

The following JavaScript running in canvas should play audio fine:

```
var audio = new Audio('tune.wav');
audio.play();
```

Most of the time it does work, the wav is 24bit 14100kbps and plays fine on several machines,  but on my laptop (Win7, using Firefox 22.0)  I get the error:

- HTTP "Content-Type" of "x-unknown/unknown" is not supported. Load of media resource file:///C:/code/sound/tune.wav failed.

I'm aware that there are other libraries to play sound, but I want to keep this pure JavaScript and since it works fine on other machines it might be a hardware problem.
But I am able to play other audio files fine, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Based upon my experience with the JS Audio elements, you're missing a line.

```
var audio = new Audio('tune.wav');
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

I don't think that's causing the error though. Based upon the responses to this question:

[Firefox won't play .WAV files using the HTML5 <audio> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404005/firefox-wont-play-wav-files-using-the-html5-audio-tag)

and the back-and-forth in this forum: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524109 (comment 7)

It looks like Firefox simply doesn't support 24-bit WAVE files. 16-bit is probably a safer option.

Comment: I obviously missed out the audio.load() and have switched the wavs to 8 bit. However the problem continued to occur when testing local files. Testing the exact same files using Mongoose, as a local-host, and the sound worked fine. Which I can't explain.