# Firefox media resource file.wav could not be decoded

Tags: html, firefox, audio, wav

Using Firefox 36.0.1
File type:

> file.wav: setgid RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711
>   A-law, mono 8000 Hz

Firefox is failing to show `<audio>` tag, and in console complains as:

> Media resource http://.../file.wav could not be decoded.

From Chrome it works.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like this question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404005/firefox-wont-play-wav-files-using-the-html5-audio-tag. Make sure you use the proper bit rate, the lowest is 8 bit. You can also fallback to say an mp3 file per the audio html5 spec. Firefox MDN lists the audio and video specs pretty nicely here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Yes it is 8 bit sample rate. Unfortunately I have asked this long time ago and not working on it anymore, so can't do anymore tests. I guess I should close the question somehow  maybe:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted it looks like your audio file is at 8000 Hz
Normally an audio file is at 48 Khz

try converting this wav file in a small program named **Audacity**, convert the file again in a wave and try again in your FireFox.

Comment: Hi, But PBX is recording audio to 8000Hz, and regarding space on devices it will stay like that. So the problem is that FF can't play 8KHz files ?

Comment: no the first line is actually description from `file file.wav` describing the codec and bitrate ,....so actually I used audacity to get the file