# How live video or audio streams work?

Tags: c#, .net, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I coding the server that generates html pages, so users can view those in their browsers.

It has onGetRequest event and this is handler for it:

```
            var req = e.Request;
            var res = e.Response;

            var path = req.RawUrl.Replace("%20", " ");
            if (path == "/")
                path += "index.html";

            if (path.Contains("/../"))
            {
                res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                return;
            }

            var content = this.ServerToRun.GetFile(path); //getting file to read
            if (content == null)
            {
                res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                return;
            }

            string extension = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('.'));

            string auto_mime = PageControls.MimeTypeDeterminer.GetMimeTypeFor(extension);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(auto_mime))
            {
                if (extension.Length > 1)
                    res.ContentType = "application/" + extension.Substring(1);
                else
                    res.ContentType = "application/unknown";
            }
            else
                res.ContentType = auto_mime;

            if (path.EndsWith(".html") || path.EndsWith(".htm"))
                res.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            res.WriteContent(content); //sending content to client
```

I don't understand what is needed to do for supporting live streams.
For example, I can record audio from microphone, so file will increase it's size every second.

I can do this in html code:

```
<audio>
    <source src = "live.wav" type = "audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

The server will receive query for this file, read it till the end and send it to client, but right after this `live.wav` will get more chunks of sound that server will not send to client anymore.

So, I am stuck, how live streams ever work and what I need to do?

I have WebSocket opened to every client, so I can call some scripts.

Comment: Try using `<audio controls>...</audio>`

Comment: @Æðelstan - how this will help me? Will it make browser to continuously request audio file or what? I though this attribute only adds control panel.

Comment: It was just something to try, but you could also try using a different file format. Try mp3 which is widely supported. Not all browsers support the same audio formats correctly. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404005/firefox-wont-play-wav-files-using-the-html5-audio-tag

Comment: @Æðelstan - I think you don't understand what I questioning since `using a different file format` is totally not related with my problem.

Comment: HTML5 does support livestreaming on the audio tag, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Æðelstan - I ask what server should do to support it? I described how file content will be sent only once.

Comment: Try not sending a Content-Length header.

Comment: Or you can use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` which is better... see here for the format : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: @Æðelstan - ok, this is at least something I should investigate. Thank you.

Comment: np:) So basically your server needs to keep the socket open until you want to stop the livestream, and keep sending bytes on the socket (which will be seen as the continuation of the response's body). I'm not sure how exactly this is done in C# though.

Comment: @Æðelstan - I made chunked response and live audio translation is kinda working, so make this tip as answer and I accept it. However audio start to play with 5 - 7 seconds delay in browser even on local machine and I can't figure the reason for it.

Comment: Oh, meh, looks like translations work in some other way, because when new client will connect in the middle of translation he will request `live.mp3` file and will listen it from the beginning in this solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by translation here? Have you solved these problems or not yet?

Comment: @Æðelstan - translation is same as streaming or live streaming. It's not converting words from one language to another. I still didn't solved delay at the beginning and every new user will be forced to listen mp3 from beginning, while stream in it's middle, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` HTTP header. This header allows you to send data in chunks without the need to specifiy a Content-Length, thus the client will not close the socket until the server indicates the last chunk has been sent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding.