# How to play MP4 video in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a dynamic video path coming from database. Video can be uploaded in any format. When I load the video in Firefox, I see the following errors

**Specified “type” attribute of “video/mp4” is not supported. Load of media resource path_to_video.mp4 failed.**

I am loading the video in my html like

```
<p>
 <video class="responsive-video" id="trailer">
   <source src="<?php echo $biovideo?>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</p>
```

Is there any way to play the mp4 videos in Firefox as I am not sure what extension the video will have

Comment: Version of Firefox? OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS FF version 50.0

Comment: Firefox needs support from the OS or hardware to play MP4 (H264) video. I am afraid it's not supported on Linux systems. You can find a support table here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats. Side note: If only have one source for the video you don't need a `source` element and therefore no `type` attribute.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Update - Feb 2019**

Firefox no longer uses GStreamer and instead interfaces directly with ffmpeg. Hence the flag mentioned below will no longer appear in current version of Firefox.

There is now a flag media.ffmpeg.enabled which again can be set to true:

- go to Firefox about:config
- search for the 'media.ffmpeg.enabled' flag
- set it to true

In practice this is not necessary on many platforms - the latest official Firefox online notes say:

> Patented media
>   MP3, AAC, and H.264/MPEG-4 AVC are patented audio/video compression formats. They can be viewed in Firefox using built-in OS libraries (so neither Mozilla nor you need to pay a fee) if embedded in the MP4 container format (.mp4, .m4a, .m4p, .m4b, .m4r, .m4v file types).

To verify, a test as at February 2019:

- With a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, Firefox could not play a test mp4 stream. It can play video using other container standards, those with the following file extensions: webm and ogg
- In the terminal ran 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras' and accepted all licenses etc
- With no other changes, i.e. no flag setting etc, Firefox can now play the test mp4 stream

**Original answer - for older versions of Firefox**

As noted in the comments Ubuntu/firefox does not support mp4 natively - this is due to licensing issues. The Mozilla documentation is a little confusing (IMHO) so the table at the bottom is probably the best place to look.

However you can add support fairly easily by installing Ubuntu extras:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

and then enabling gstreamer:

- go to Firefox about:config
- search for the 'media.gstreamer.enabled' flag
- set it to enabled

This should allow you play the video.

Comment: Not sure that flag still exists, but installing that package and rebooting firefox seems to do the trick.

Comment: In FF65 I do not see this flag anymore.

Comment: @Felix, and sethrin - thanks for the notes. It seems Firefox no longer uses GStreamer but uses ffmpeg directly instead.

Comment: @Mick I have trouble with Firefox (only tested on mac) and mp4/h264/PCM audio. The file plays in the browser but there is no sound. Is that related to the patent issue you mentioned? If I encode the same file with aac audio it plays in Firefox. Is there any way around this? Both Safari and Chrome plays h246 with PCM audio without problem.

Comment: @SeaBass - can you share an example of a video where the audio does not play?

Comment: @Mick Sure, this does not play audio in Firefox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/73qlamzfkuqpm25/bbb_PCM_48_16.mov?dl=0 Any ideas why? It even has the speaker symbol muted as if I hit mute myself.

Comment: If you compare to this file that I encoded with AAC audio which does play in firefox. But it's a huge inconvenience with our workflow to take that extra step on a huge amount of video files, just so it can play in firefox. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fiimyd87rxsu1th/bbb_AAC_48_192.mov?dl=0

Comment: @SeaBass - It frustrating as it does not play as you say and also gives no error message. I don't think it is related to this answer above. Firefox seems to be picky about audio formats (see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404005/334402). If you do find the root cause can you share it here. One thing to note - ffmpeg does have some history of discussion with PCM_16be which is the format in your video, in particular with muxing it into different containers. As Firefox is now using ffmpeg this may provide some pointer to the issue.

Comment: Thanks. So no luck huh :/ Wave files are playing fine for me. Just h264 with PCM audio.

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu **20.04**, run:

> apt install libavcodec58

Comment: This just works.

Comment: im on win 11 how to do this in ff on win 11? i wish to play mp4 nativly?