# html 5 video tag preload attribute not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, video

```
  <video class="student-video" controls preload="none">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

somehow this works perfectly in chrome but doesn't work in firefox.
Is there anyway for firefox to prevent autoplay?

Comment: Hum... what do you mean ? `preload` attribute is just about preloading the media. Borwsers don't have to follow it, and they'll most of the time make some genuine checks (like which internet connection you're on) before following this attribute. But in no way your video should `autoplay`. This is a completely different attribute, which must default to `false`. I guess you've got something that does trigger the playing of this video.

Comment: @Kaiido I believe it's some browser setting thing.  Found a way, it works but not sure if it's the best by pausing it right on start using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about this problem, you can try this:

1. Go to Preferences > Advanced > General
2. In Browsing section, unmark the "Use hardware acceleration when available:
3. Save it.

Now restart Firefox and check your video.

It may help you, in some cases this is also issue.

You can also try this:
[How to play MP4 video in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760864/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-firefox?rq=1)

Comment: yes but I don't want that though because I can't ask everyone browsing the website to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "proload" option from the code and test